# Different ASP.NET Identity cookie expire time in some browsers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-identity, expired-cookies

I've encountered a strange problem in ASP.NET Identity 2. I've used Cookie 
Authentication in ASP.NET Identity 2.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            },
            SlidingExpiration = true,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)
        });
```

Every thing is OK except cookie expire time in some browsers. I know I have to use `CookieAuthenticationOptions.ExpireTimespan` for setting the time that cookie is valid and I set it to an hour (`ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)`). In some browsers it works properly, but in some other browsers it expires every five minutes and users logout and have to login again in every 5 minutes!

If it is a problem in my project or IIS settings, why in some browsers it works fine without any problems? I even checked the versions of browsers and they were the same! I Even guessed It may be because of a plug-in installed on those browsers, so I uninstalled that browser and installed it again! But the problem was still there.

The interesting point is that in one system it was OK on chrome but in IE and Firefox the problem was exist. Or in another computer it was OK on Firefox but when the Firefox updated the problem appeared!

I'm really confused. Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem and why it is only in some browsers?

Comment: Pls add code where you set Expiry time for the cookie

Comment: @User3250 See my update post.

Comment: To quote from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions.aspx): *CookieAuthenticationOptions.ExpireTimeSpan [...] The expiration information is in the protected cookie ticket*  I would assume that you are looking at the default expiration time values specified by the browsers. The actual Asp.Net expire time is part of the cookie value.

Comment: Thank you @ckerth. But I use default Asp.Net Identity settings and don't change something in expiration time values specified by the browsers. So what should I do?

Comment: Have you verified if the server actually responds with the correct cookie (debug the response on server side)? If yes the expiration date is probably modified by the client or somewhere in between. I don't know if you can handle these cases server-side. If you have access to the client code you could set the expiration date of the cookie on the client.